# Browsing two sites on the same IIS server

Tags: wcf, iis, web, server, host

I uploaded two websites on a single IIS local server. One that hosts a WFC service other that consumes it 
I know that using host header to distinguish them in not an option without a DNS server, so I gave the first one an all assigned IP ad the second one 172.20.1.44, whenever I try to browse to it locally it gives me the connection timed out
how could I browse to the second site on my local machine to test it

Answer (score 0):

Put them on different ports.  Put one site on * 80 and the other on * 8080.  You can modify the port in the binding screen of IIS.

[image]